# Magento fatal error lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5, out-of-memory

We added few products in Magento admin and uploaded few product images as well.After that my product listing page is blank.So i checked my error_log file i saw the below error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 190578688) (tried to allocate 7896 bytes) in /public_html/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 44
```

So i disabled all last added products. Cleared cache. Re-indexed,Cache Enabled.

My Memory limit = 512M

What the hell is this. Anyone has solution please post it.

Comment: Whats wrong with my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

190578688 bytes is 181 MB.  That means either

1. Your server is physically RAM constrained.  You can set whatever you like in your php.ini, but it doesn't matter is the RAM isn't available to the OS
2. Something (.htaccess, ini_set calls, different php.ini) is overriding the 512 MB you set
3. The errors you're seeing in your log are related to another problem

To check for #3, turn on developer mode in `index.php`, and set the `display_errors` ini file to "1", and then attempt to load your product page.  This should output your error directly to the browser.

Comment: i found the problem. 4 MB size image was uploaded to the product.So system unable to load this image. Anyway thanks for the good points.

Comment: Let me know whats the right dimension and size of image. Magento will accept.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be common thing. We had a shop which was running on weak server. Each page was about 30 "big" thumbnails about 60 "small" thumbnails and about 90 big images. After adding 5-10 products we were getting the same error.

One of the wodoo-magic would be refreshing page till there will be low amount of users on the server and hopefully PHP will have enough memory to change the size of image. LOL :D

The better solution would be to change the sources of images to worst quality, so PHP won't struggle against large JPEGs or PNGs. Or resize the image before uploading to the needed size.

The best solution might be to write some cron-walker, which checks resized images, and if there is no such in cache it makes it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove images bigger than 350Kb in your catalog.

Also in System/Configuration/General/Design the images you use for the watermarks and upload optimized images in jpg. That did the trick for me!